# Why Sikuli is not able to find the image path

Tags: eclipse, macos, selenium, sikuli

I am trying to open simple gmail link on google home page but image path is not getting detected by Sikuli here please help and yes I am working on Mac OS system. Is it something to do with my `sikulixapi` jar placement? I have placed it here:

```
/Users/vishalsrivastava/Documents/JARS/SikuliJar/sikulixapi.jar
```

and no matter what image or what path I am trying, Sikuli always returns error and exceptions. I am totally confused.

```
package sikuli;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.sikuli.script.*;

public class TestSikuli {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://google.com/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Screen s = new Screen();
        try{
            Pattern gmail=new Pattern("/Users/vishalsrivastava/Documents/workspace/SeleniumTest/imgs/gmail.png");
            s.click(gmail);

        }
        catch(FindFailed e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

[image: See the path of Image file.Still why sikuli is not liking it]

[image: What is purpose of ImagesAPi.sikuli ??]

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here does not seem to be the path. You can see what you get is the Sikuli `FindFailed` exception which means that the pattern you are looking for was not found on the screen or region.

You have to ensure that the pattern you are looking for is actually on the screen. Few things to check are:

1. The pattern is exactly similar to the area you are trying to find on the screen.
2. Colors and shades
3. Timing. Maybe Sikuli times out before it finds the pattern. That can happen if the screen has been recently changed, like if you just navigated there.\

**EDIT**:
If you want to know for sure what is the path used by Sikuli, you can print it out like this:

```
System.out.println(ImagePath.getBundlePath());
```

Comment: Thanks for reply .I'll try to explain my problem here i am new to sikuli so dam not able to figure it out but it seems sikuli in my eclipse tool is not working or something i don't know.

Comment: I have updated my query with other screen shots and code please have a look and help.

Comment: thanks!  yes i saw and  linked the edited version.I am new to stack overflow as well so still learning.

Answer (score 0):

I think 'Eugene S' is giving some usefull tips, but I would like to add something to it. 
You can use `.focusedWindow()` to locate the window that has focus/is in front. 
Next I find `.highlight()` usefull as well, because it gives an idea where Sikuli is focusing on when looking for some image. 
I use it a little bit for some fast debugging I guess.

Comment: I afraid highlight won't be helpful here as the pattern wasn't found.

Answer (score 0):

As Eugene and Tenzin mention, there are numerous reasons an image may not be found. In typical GUI automation, you need to figure this out by trial-and-error.

Since the images we choose have a large impact on the success of our automation, it is important to choose them wisely. Optimally, we would do an analysis of our images on our target environment before writing any code. Knowing, before we start coding, if images are found, if they are found in multiple places, in which locations and in which states of our environment they are found, can save us a lot of time and frustration down the line. With image analysis we will also have the answers for questions like this one in Stack Overflow.

The process of image selection and analysis is one of the key features of **Brobot**, an open-source automation framework for Java that wraps SikuliX functions. The [Brobot documentation](https://jspinak.github.io/brobot/) has a [tutorial](https://jspinak.github.io/brobot/docs/tutorial-state-structure-builder/intro) on how to build the backbone of your automation, with links to a [video series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SmeIc06_GUg&list=PLC2shVr9gxdneSx0AuEv_YXwQsvUd9DuX) that discusses image selection and [preliminary image analysis](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6sO0tcXXyG8&t=10s).

*Disclaimer*: I'm the developer of Brobot. It's free and open source.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion - you should make it clear that you are affiliated with the project you are recommending.

Comment: thanks David for the advice :) i added the disclaimer