# Sikuli does not recognize any image

Tags: robotframework, sikuli

Sikuli does not regognize any image even if I set `Set Min Similarity` to `0.15`.

Indeed, I try to do some actions on Notepad++.

Notepad is opened with command `Open Application`. But all next steps crashed.

The first error is the following one : `com.github.rainmanwy.robotframework.sikulilib.exceptions.TimeoutException: Timeout happened, could not find P(newfile.png) S: 0.15000000596046448`.

Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: Is the image you are searching for very small or very large?

Comment: It is small I guess. It is the new file button on NotePad++.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the location of the image, or to use a full path.

Answer (score 0):

Figuring out why an image is not found requires a lot of trial-and-error with typical GUI automation. For example, differences between the image on file and the image on-screen, the wrong path to the file, shading and transparency on-screen, min similarity, the search timing out before an image appears, or one of numerous other potential errors. There is a way around the trial-and-error, and it involves doing an analysis of all your images on your target environment before starting to code. My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73071190/13361997) goes into more detail on how to do this.